# macOS not allowing me to restore media files from one external drive to another

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, partition, restore

> I am trying to restore media from an external drive to another
>   external drive now both the partitions have been formatted with the
>   same partition map GUID partition map (I am also getting an APFS
>   partition message on clicking the partition map option available under
>   disk utility)). Now whenever I am trying to restore the partitions, I am coming across several errors.

**This was the first attempt:** I selected the main volume (as the source volume from which the media files are to be restored) which is at the top of the volume tree (Sandisk Ultramedia)

I am facing this error! (I have attached some screenshots to further explain my problem)

**Error No.1**

[image][image]
[image]

**Error No.2**

This time I selected the volume within the container APFS volume (as the source disk from where the media files are to be restored) which is the Sandisk USB External Drive/MacOS USB. But, again I got the same error.

[image]
[image]

Comment: *Please* post just the error message and not your whole desktop - it makes it very difficult to read.

Comment: @Allan sorry I forgot to crop the pics in hurry, I'll do it right away.

Comment: A tip for screenshotting so you don't have to crop the images each time and it'll look better: If you press ⌘ + Shift + 4 instead of 3, a different kind of cursor will pop up, and if you hit space you can take screenshots of individual windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with macOS Mojave. Even I tried to do the same. I came across the same errors you are facing. Luckily, I was able to clone the disks  which is same as restoring.

There are several ways to clone a disk. You can use some utility tools available on and off the macOS App Store.

I tried this ***https://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html*** cloning utility to clone my main drive to an external SSD both having the same partition map - APFS. This should solve the problem.

Comment: I downloaded the app and it did work. Now my problem is solved.